# What is Purchase.getPurchaseState() in IabHelper?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm implementing in app purchase using IabHelper library. I'm trying to retrieve the status of purchase using `purchase.getPurchaseState()`, but I'm unable to figure out the what the constant returned by this methods means.

What are the meaning of values returned by this method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html:

> purchaseState - The purchase state of the order. It always returns 0 (purchased).

As I remember, previously there were also the other values:

```
1 (canceled)
2 (refunded)
```

but I can't find the reference on the last version on the docs.

Comment: This document states PURCHASED state is 1. https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase.PurchaseState